# google chart integration in xamarin forms android and ios apps.

Tags: xamarin, charts, xamarin.forms

Can someone assist me how to integrate google charts in xamarin forms android and ios app? As I am new to xamarin forms development. Can anyone tell me whether its possible or not?

Comment: Google charts are JavaScript based and are supported on the browsers (and browser widgets) within Android and iOS and thus you can use the Xamarin.Forms' WebView to display them

Comment: Google charts are slow and and has been removed from xamarin as an SDK and if you like to do it with a webview you can always use oxy plot : http://www.oxyplot.org/

Answer (score 0):

No as of now we cannot integrate google charts in any of the mobile technologies but can use webview to show the charts in apps